# why is div element behaving like a container?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, containers

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
  <h1>Hello World</p>
    <p>This is the content of the p element. It shrinks when I shrink the viewport</p>
</div>
```

Why is the content shrinking on resizing the viewport even though it does not have a *container* class? (any example to witness the difference between *div* having container-class and a non-container *div* will be highly appreciated)

Comment: Isn't the difference just that Bootstrap will size your container for you if it's a container, and if it's not a bootstrap container, you manually size it? The contents would shrink because the div is a container, just not a bootstrap managed container.

Hopefully you get some other answers, though, because I've barely used bootstrap.

Comment: That's how div elements behave by default.

Answer (score 0):

By default a `div` has 100% width, so it will shrink with the viewport if that is resized (and if the div is a direct child of `body` or of any other element that always fills the viewport's width).

Bootstrap has certain classes, but if none of those is used, a div must still behave like a "regular" div (i.e. any div without using bootstrap)

Comment: I have just tried and specified the width of the outer div and made an inner div, it didn't resize. So far so good. But its not even shrinking even if I add contain class to the div?

Comment: Once you add a specific width (in a fixed unit like px) the div wont shrink or grow anymore (because you set the width to a fixed value).